# adding multiple circles around a pin in iOS

Tags: ios, mkmapview, geometry

How can I add and display multiple circles in different colors inside a map (`MKMapView`)? I figured out how to add **one** circle, but can't figure out how to add multiple circles in various sizes and colors ... any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code I use to draw two concentric circles at a given location on the map.  The outer one is gray, and the inner one is white.  (in my example "range" is the circle radius)  Both have some transparency:

```objc
- (void)drawRangeRings: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) where {
    // first, I clear out any previous overlays:
    [mapView removeOverlays: [mapView overlays]];
    float range = [self.rangeCalc currentRange] / MILES_PER_METER;
    MKCircle* outerCircle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate: where radius: range];
    outerCircle.title = @"Stretch Range";
    MKCircle* innerCircle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate: where radius: (range / 1.425f)];
    innerCircle.title = @"Safe Range";

    [mapView addOverlay: outerCircle];
    [mapView addOverlay: innerCircle];
}
```

Then, make sure your class implements the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol, and define how your overlays look in the following method:

```objc
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {
    MKCircle* circle = overlay;
    MKCircleView* circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle: circle];
    if ([circle.title compare: @"Safe Range"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        circleView.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.25];
        circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else {
        circleView.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:0.25];
        circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
    circleView.lineWidth = 2.0;

    return circleView;
}
```

And, of course, don't forget to set the delegate on your `MKMapView` object, or the above method will never get called:

```objc
mapView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: does this display both circles at the same time?

Comment: yes.  they are drawn on top of each other (smaller white circle on top of larger grey circle).  obviously, if you want the two (or more) circles to have **different** center locations, you would need to change my code so that the same value is not passed to `circleWithCenterCoordinate:` for both circles.